# Getting Account ID from Segment.io Salesforce (Actions) Mapping to Create Contact

Tags: segment-io

The Salesforce (Actions) destination in Segment allows one to map Accounts and also Contacts. I'm using this for upserts upon receipt of an identify call.

Their [documentation](https://segment.com/docs/connections/destinations/catalog/actions-salesforce/#contact) says, that for a contact to be associated with an account, the account ID must be provided.

> The ID of the account that this contact is associated with. This is the Salesforce-generated ID assigned to the account during creation (i.e. 0018c00002CDThnAAH).

Fair enough, but the account is created by Segment using another mapping from the same identify. So how can I get the newly created account ID from that step to include in the Account ID field of the contact mapping triggered by the same identify?

The account ID is required to map the new contact to an existing account. But the account ID doesn't exist except as created by another mapping, which isn't made available as a variable in the current context.

[Account ID field customer mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct6G9.png)

Simply, how can a single identify event - not having a pre-existing account ID - trigger the creation of both a new account and a related contact using the Segment Salesforce (Actions) destination?

I've tried configuring the mappings in different orders to see if Segment could just recognize that it was itself creating the new account ID. I would expect that at some point the ID it's creating, which I can see in testing, is made available to the other mappings, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Segment support says it’s not possible to create a new account and a new related contact at the same time from a single Identify.

The account ID needs to be Included in the identify to create a contact related to the account being created. But the account ID doesn’t exist before Segment creates the account, so can't be included in the Identify.

Very frustrating.